# Showing that $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on the interval $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

Suppose that $f$: $[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and differentiable on $(1, \infty)$ with  bounded derivative. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous. (HINT: split $[0, \infty)$ into two pieces, on each of which $f$ is uniformly continuous, then explain why this implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on the whole $[0, \infty)$.)

**Question:** I have solved the majority of the problem, but wanted a little clarification with regards to the explanation in the second part. Specifically there is the situation where:

$ x \in [0, 1)$ and  $y > 1$ (or vice versa). In this scenario I still have to show $|x - y| < \delta$. Given the conditions that I have can I do the following: $$|x - y| \leq |x - 1| + |y - 1| < \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$$

And if this is allowed is the reason that I should choose $1$ because the two intervals split at that specific point so it allows me to relate $x,y$ to each other?

Assuming the previous step is true then it follows:

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f(1) + |f(1) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Comment: Yes. I do ....I picked [0,1] and $(1,\infty)$ for that reason

Comment: The implication was that you can have the intervals overlap and not have to worry about the $x$ and the $y$ being in separate ``domains''; that is, instead of $[0,2]\cup[2,\infty)$, you could take $[0,2]\cup[3/2,\infty)$. Now simply enforce $|x-y|<\frac12$ and both $x,y$ will be in the same domain.

Comment: However, the $\delta$ you are looking for is the minimum of both $\delta$s for each domain, where $\varepsilon /2$ is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVT to show $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$ on $(1,\infty)$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x,y\in[0,1]$. If $x\le 1\le y$, because $f$ is continuous at $1$,  there is $\eta$ so that if $|x-y|<\eta$ implies $|x-1|,|y-1|<\eta$ and
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f(1)|+|f(1)-f(y)|<\epsilon $$
Now if $|x-y|<\min\{\epsilon/M,\delta,\eta\}$, we get $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: This provides more clarity to my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem gives Lipschitz and therefore uniform continuity 
of $f$ in $[1,\infty)$ including $1$. That is because you need 
differentiablity only in the interior. Moreover, $f$ is uniformly 
continuous in $[0,1]$ since every continuous function on compact sets 
are automatically uniformly continuous.

Now, let be $\varepsilon > 0$. Then,
there exist $\delta_{1/2}$ such that $$ \lvert f(x_i) - f(1) \rvert < 
\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$ for $\lvert x_i - 1 \rvert < \delta_i$ where $0 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \leq x_2$. Of course, $\delta_i$ does not depend on $1$ nor $x_i$ due to the uniform continuity; this is important. Hence, 
if we choose $\delta = \min\{ \delta_1,\delta_2 \}$, we obtain $$ \lvert 
f(x_1) - f(x_2) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x_1) - f(1) \rvert + \lvert f(1) - 
f(x_2) \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = 
\varepsilon$$ since $$\lvert x_i - 1 \rvert \leq \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert < \delta \leq \delta_i$$
for $0 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \leq x_2$. For arbitrary $x_1,x_2$ both entirely in either $[0,1]$ or $[1,\infty)$, we can use the same $\delta$ due to the choices of each $\delta_i$, which proves the statement.